# How to calculate $1900^{13} \pmod{2537}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> How to calculate $1900^{13} \pmod{2537}$

I should be able to do this problem but I don't figure a fast way of calculating it.

Edit: I find reduced the problem to solve:

$X≡12^{13}$mod$59$ and $X≡2^{39}$mod$43$

and I don't know how to solve

$X≡12^{13}$mod$59$

Comment: not sure if will help but $2537+13=2550$

Comment: Note that $2537=43\cdot59$ so you can do mod $43$ and mod $59$ and then use the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: @saulspatz I tried that but it's complicated.

Comment: Can you post your efforts, please?  It's hard to help you if I can't see where you are having difficulty.

Comment: @saulspatz I've trouble with solving $X\equiv 12^{13} mod 59$

Comment: Hunch: $59 = 5*12-1$ and so $12^2\equiv 144=120+24=2(60-1)+26\equiv 26$.  And $12^3\equiv 26*12\equiv 25*12+12\equiv 5(5*12)+12\equiv 5(5*12-1)+17\equiv 17\pmod {59}$  And $12^{6}\equiv 17^2\equiv (12+5)(12+5)\equiv 144 + 5*12 + 5*12 + 25\equiv 26 + 1+1+25\equiv 53\equiv -6\pmod {59}$.  And $12^{12}\equiv (-6)^2\equiv 36$.  So $12^{13}\equiv 36*12\equiv 5*7*12 + 12\equiv 7(5*12 -1) + 19\equiv 19\pmod {59}$.

Comment: But even if  didn't have the hunch you can do $12^2=144\equiv 26$.  $12^4\equiv 26^2\equiv 676\equiv 27$.  $12^{12}\equiv 27^3\equiv 19683\equiv 36$ and $12^{13}\equiv 36*12\equiv 432\equiv 19$.  ...Although I have to admit that $12^4\equiv 12^2 + 1$ is intriguing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute $p=12^{13}\bmod 59$, you can use the fast exponentiation algorithm (‘square and divide’):

\begin{array}{rlll}
n&x& &p \\
\hline
13 & x=12& &p=12 \\
6 &x^2=26&&\phantom{p={}}12 \\
3& x^4=26^2=27&&p=27\cdot 12=29 \\
1&x^8=27^2=21&&p=21\cdot 29=\color{red}{19} \\
\hline
\end{array}

As to $2^{39}\bmod 43$, by *lil' Fermat*, it is $2^{-3}=8^{-1}$, and the *extended Euclidean algorithm* yields in a few steps that
$$8^{13}=-22.$$